# Question on using sed, filtering data

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

Here is a sample text file:

```
store: xxx
Delete: xxx
Expires: Sat, 30 Oct 02021 13:01:57 +0100
store: xxx
Delete: xxx
Expires: Sat, 30 Oct 02021 13:01:57 +0100
store: abc
store: sdf
Expires: Sat, 30 Oct 02021 13:01:57 +0100
```

- I want all three fields (`store`, `Delete`, `Expires`) in a CSV format.
- If there is no `Delete` or `Expires` line/string, it should show as `null` or empty space separated with a comma
- The date field to be trimmed to be only `DD Mon YYYY` e.g. `30 Oct 2001`

So far with the help, we have the below but does not work as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
cat list.txt | grep -E "Expires|Delete|Store" | awk '{ printf "%s\n", $2 }' | tr  '\n' ',' | sed 's/,,/\n/' | sed '$ s/.$//'
```

Comment: Do the lines in the file actually start with `>`?

Comment: First, you don't need to pipe `cat` into `grep` or `awk`. The latter utilities send to `stdout` anyway. Secondly, add the expected output to your question.

Comment: Two consecutive lines are saying `store:`, how should that be handled? Your command at the end seems to mention things that are not part of the file at the top, like `X-Delete-At` and `Object`. Do zeros always prefix the years in the data? Could you please make your text consistent please?

Comment: Does your file actually have lines beginning with `>` and some whitespace?  If not, then don't post it as if it does.  just paste your sample data into the question and mark it as code by either selecting the data and pressing Ctrl-K or adding a line with just ``` (three backticks) immediately before and immediately after the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your attempt (why `X-Delete-At`, why `Object:`, how do you want to deal with missing fields?), so I suggest an `sed`-only-solution:

```
sed -nE '/Expires:/{s/: [^,]*,/:/;s/0([0-9]{4})/\1_/}
  /store/!{H;$!d;}
  x;s/.*store: ([[:alnum:]]*)[^>]*[> ]*(Delete: ([[:alnum:]]*)[^>]*[> ]*)*(Expires: ([^_]*))*.*/\1,\3,\5/p
  $!d
  x;s/.*store: ([[:alnum:]]*).*/\1,,/p' /tmp/list.txt
```

The idea is to collect fields in the hold space until the next `store:` line, then `x`change buffers, so the next `store:` line is already in the buffer and the collected fields can be formatted for output.

The trick is in the complex regular expression. The optional fields are put inside `()*`, so they can appear any number of times. If they don't appear at all, the whole regexp still matches.

To eat up the junk without eating the optional fields along, I did choose `[^>]*` instead of `.*`, making use of the lines beginning with `>`.

The first line is for reformatting the date.
The last two lines handle the case when the file ends with a `store:` line.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I am trying to break it down and understand what each field is doing based on your practical examples but i get no result back?

Comment: sed -nE '/Expires:/{s/: [^,]*,/:/;s/0([0-9]{4})/\1_/}'  /tmp/list.txt  -- returns no result?

Comment: The `-n` suppresses default output. In the whole script the output is generated by the `p` flags to the `s`ubstitute commands. If you want to analyse only this script, either drop the `-n` option to see all output or add `p` at the end to see the `Expires` lines only.